# Appending to bibliographic collection in OpenalexR

Tags: r, append, tibble, doi

I would like to combine two bibliographic collections that I have downloaded with openalexR, by appending the second to the first.

In my minimal example, I download only one work for each collection and want to append the second to the first. However, my result is not a tibble with two observations, but a "list of 72".

```
library(openalexR)

works_from_dois1 <- oa_fetch(
  entity = "works",
  doi = c("10.1080/1369183X.2016.1176906")
)

works_from_dois2 <- oa_fetch(
  entity = "works",
  doi = c("10.1016/j.socnet.2013.11.001")
)

str(works_from_dois1)

works_from_dois_all <- append(works_from_dois1,works_from_dois2)

str(works_from_dois_all)
```

I would appreciate any help!
Richard

Comment: The function `oa_fetch` will return a tibble data.frame, not a vector. So, you can try using `rbind(works_from_dois1, works_from_dois2)` to add rows of one tibble to another (or `bind_rows` from `dplyr`). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This has worked, thanks!